# Comma separated list on MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database

I am implementing a friends list for users in my database, where the list will store the friends accountID.

I already have a similar structure in my database for achievements where I have a separate table that has a pair of accountID to achievementID, but my concern with this approach is that it is inefficient because if there are 1 million users with 100 achievements each there are 100million entries in this table. Then trying to get every achievement for a user with a certain accountID would be a linear scan of the table (I think).

I am considering having a comma separated string of accountIDs for my friends list table, I realize how annoying it will be to deal with the data as a string, but at least it would be guaranteed to be log(n) search time for a user with accountID as the primary key and the second column being the list string.

Am I wrong about the search time for these two different structures?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL can make effective use of appropriate indexes, for queries designed to use those indexes, avoiding a "scan" operation on the table.

If you are ALWAYS dealing with the complete set of achievements for a user, retrieving the entire set, and storing the entire set, then a comma separated list in a single column can be a workable approach.

**HOWEVER...** that design breaks down when you want to deal with individual achievements. For example, if you want to retrieve a list of users that have a particular achievement. Now, you're doing expensive full scans of all achievements for all users, doing "string searches", dependent on properly formatted strings, and MySQL is unable to use an index scan to efficiently retrieve that set.

So, the rule of thumb, if you **NEVER** need to individually access an achievement, and **NEVER** need to remove an achievement from user in the database, and **NEVER** need to add an individual achievement for a user, and you will **ONLY EVER** pull the achievements as an entire set, and only store them as an entire set, in and out of the database, the comma separated list is workable.

---

I hesitate to recommend that approach, because it never turns out that way. Inevitably, you'll want a query to get a list of users that have a particular achievement.

With the comma separated list column, you're into some ugly SQL:

```
SELECT a.user_id
  FROM user_achievement_list a
 WHERE CONCAT(',',a.list,',') LIKE '%,123,%'
```

ugly in the sense that MySQL can't use an index range scan to satisfy the predicate; MySQL has to look at EVERY SINGLE list of achievements, and then do a string scan on each and every one of them, from the beginning to the end, to find out if a row matches or not.

And it's downright excruciating if you want to use the individual values in that list to do a join operation, to "lookup" a row in another table. That SQL just gets horrendously ugly.

And declarative enforcement of data integrity is impossible; you can't define any foreign key constraints that restrict the values that are added to the list, or remove all occurrences of a particular `achievement_id` from every list it occurs in.

Basically, you're "giving up" the advantages of a relational data store; so don't expect the database to be able to do any work with that type of column. As far as the database is concerned, it's just a blob of data, might as well be .jpg image stored in that column, MySQL isn't going to help with retrieving or maintaining the contents of that list.

On the other hand, if you go with a design that stores the individual rows, each achievement for each user as a separate row, and you have an appropriate index available, the database can be MUCH more efficient at returning the list, and the SQL is more straightforward:

```
SELECT a.user_id
  FROM user_achievements a
 WHERE a.achievement_id = 123
```

A covering index would be appropriate for that query:

```
... ON user_achievements (achievement_id, user_id)
```

An index with `user_id` as the leading column would be suitable for other queries:

```
... ON user_achievements (user_id, achievement_id)
```

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see the access plan that MySQL generates.

For your example, retrieving all achievements for a given user, MySQL can do a range scan on the index to quickly locate the set of rows for the one user. MySQL doesn't need to look at every page in the index, the index is structured as a tree (at least, in the case of B-Tree indexes) so it can basically eliminate a whole boatload of pages it "knows" that the rows you are looking for can't be. And with the `achievement_id` also in the index, MySQL can return the resultset right from the index, without a need to visit the pages in the underlying table. (For the InnoDB engine, the PRIMARY KEY is the cluster key for the table, so the table itself is effectively an index.)

With a two column InnoDB table `(user_id, achievement_id)`, with those two columns as the composite PRIMARY KEY, you would only need to add one secondary index, on `(achievement_id, user_id)`.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

**Q**: By secondary index, do you mean a 3rd column that contains the key for the composite (userID, achievementID) table. My create table query looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE `UserFriends`
(`AccountID`       BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
,`FriendAccountID` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
,`Key`             BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, PRIMARY KEY (`Key`)
, UNIQUE KEY `AccountID` (`AccountID`, `FriendAccountID`)
);
```

**A:** No, I don't mean the addition of a third column. If the only two columns in the table are the foreign keys to another table (looks like they refer to the same table, and the columns are both NOT NULL and there is a UNIQUE constraint on the combination of the columns... and there are no other attributes on the table, I would consider not using a surrogate as the primary key at all. I would make the UNIQUE KEY the PRIMARY KEY.

Personally, I would be using InnoDB, with the `innodb_file_per_table` option enabled. And my table definition would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user_friend
( account_id            BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'PK, FK ref account.id'
, friend_account_id     BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'PK, FK ref account.id'
, PRIMARY KEY (account_id, friend_account_id)
, UNIQUE KEY user_friend_UX1 (friend_account_id, account_id)
, CONSTRAINT FK_user_friend_user FOREIGN KEY (account_id)
    REFERENCES account (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
, CONSTRAINT FK_user_friend_friend FOREIGN KEY (friend_account_id)
    REFERENCES account (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) Engine=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Thanks for the great post, as a follow up to my most important question, would finding an achievement or all achievements from the table be O(n)? There will be multiple accountID entries in the table, so I'm not sure how the database could optimize this search like it does for primary keys (which must be unique).

Comment: @Josh Brittain: with an appropriate covering index, retrieval can be even MORE efficient than with a primary key. (It depends on how many rows you are returning; and having them returned in "index order" can avoid a "Using filesort" operation, which can be expensive for large sets.

Comment: By secondary index, do you mean a 3rd column that contains the key for the composite (userID, achievementID) table. My create table query looks like this `CREATE TABLE 'UserFriends' ('AccountID' bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL, 'FriendAccountID' bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL, 'Key' bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY ('Key'), UNIQUE KEY 'AccountID' ('AccountID', 'FriendAccountID'));`